# jQuery hide appended div items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and I am trying to hide/show only the inner/appended items, such as text1, text2 and text3:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <a href="#" id="clickItem">LINK</a>
    <br />
    text1
    <br />
    text2
    <br />
    text3
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var hide = false;
$("#clickItem").click(function (e) {
    if (hide == false) {
        $("#div1").hide();
        hide = true;
        return;
    }
        else {
            $("#div1").show();
            hide = false;
            return;
        }
});
```

Comment: put all text items into `span` tag

Comment: Why not put your text1, text2, and text3 into separate divs or spans with IDs and then hide those using jquery?  e.g. `<span id="text1span">text1</span>`  and `$("#text1span").hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap the inner text in a div and toggle the inner div onclick of the link. please check below snippet for more idea.

```js
var hide = false;
$("#clickItem").click(function (e) {
  $("#innerPart").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <a href="#" id="clickItem">LINK</a>
  <div id="innerPart">
    <br />
    text1
    <br />
    text2
    <br />
    text3
  </div>                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1) you can add new div inside div below the "a" tag and apply code on inner part with id.

2) or use ".children()" and leave 1st for "a" tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to `hide` text fragments inside of a text node in a HTML document. jQuery's `hide` and `show` ultimately work with the CSS style `display` of an HTML element. So you need a wrapping HTML element, a `span` or `div` for applying jQuery's `show` and `hide`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="idDiv">
  <a href="#" id="clickItem" onClick="toggleFunction()">LINK</a>
  <div id="idText">
    <br /> text1
    <br /> text2
    <br /> text3
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

We can use onclick attribute to call the functions.

```
      function toggleFunction() {
    $("#idText").toggle();
    alert("ok");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all text items into a `span` tag and use `toggle` function to switch the text items visibility:

```js
$("#clickItem").on('click', function(){ 
   $(".innerText", $(this).parent()).toggle(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
    <a href="#" id="clickItem">LINK</a>
    <br />
    <span class='innerText'>text1
    <br />
    text2
    <br />
    text3</span>
</div>
```